# VS code extension : Add new keybindings in package.json based on a boolean value in extension configuration

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a vs code extension with these contributes in package.json

Here I have a configuration called `addKeyBoardShortcuts` which is a boolean and when user checks this I want the `keybindings` array to be updated only when the boolean is `true`

Right now the `editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne` command keybinding is always there when this extension is enabled, but I want this keybinding to only be present when `addKeyBoardShortcuts` is checked by the user.

Any help is much appreciated !

```
  "contributes": {
    "keybindings": [
      {
          "command": "editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne",
          "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
          "mac": "cmd+shift+i"
      }
    ],
    "configuration": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Rem to Px comment configuration",
      "properties": {
        "remToPxComment.commentColor": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "#36C210",
          "description": "Decoration color for the comment value"
        },
        "remToPxComment.remConversionValue": {
          "type": "number",
          "default": "16",
          "description": "value to convert px to rem, default is 16px"
        },
        "remToPxComment.convertToRemOrPx": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "px",
          "enum": [
            "px",
            "rem"
          ],
          "description": "tell if conversion is from rem to px to the other way around"
        },
        "remToPxComment.addKeyBoardShortcuts": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "default": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: in your code copy the value of the setting to a context variable and use that context variable in a `when` clause of the key binding

Comment: You don't want the contributed keybinding to show up in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` at all if the configuration is false?  I don't think that is possible.  You can disable it by the `when` clause as rioV8 suggests - and there is an easier way than to set a contextVariable - but it will still show in the `Keyboard Shortcuts`.  I will show an easier way to disable (but not remove) the keybinding based on your contributed setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, if you are trying to avoid showing the contributed keybinding in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor I don't think that is possible.  You can disable/enable it based on your contributed setting pretty easily though.

In your `package.json`:

```
  "configuration": [
   {
    "title": "Folder Operations",
    "properties": {
     "folder-operations.enableKeybinding": {       // your setting name
      "type": "boolean",
      "scope": "machine",
      "default": true,
      "markdownDescription": "your description here"
     }
    }
   }
  ],
 "keybindings": [
   {
     "command": "editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne",
     "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
     "mac": "cmd+shift+i",
     "when": "config.folder-operations.enableKeybinding"  // your extension
   }
 ]
]
```

The context key `config.folder-operations.enableKeybinding` will be true or false depending on the value of your setting - whether it remains at the default or is changed by the user.  Start the context key with the `config.` and vscode will automatically retrieve the setting's value each time the keybinding is triggered.